# Is it possible to ensure that only unique messages (differentiated by a custom ID) are sent to a Kafka topic?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, queue, message-queue

I'm considering an architecture where I have 10 different NodeJS instances acting as Producers sending messages to a Kafka topic, and these instances also act as Consumers of the same topic (the topic functions as a message queue). I'd like to ensure that messages sent to the topic are unique, that is, any new message that is being stored in the topic should be something that wasn't stored in the topic before.

Note that my problem is not with duplication of messages because of repeated tries from the Producer, I want to ensure that the topic only stores unique messages throughout. I came across the log compaction feature, but that stores the latest duplicate message, whereas I only ever want to store the earliest duplicate. Does Kafka provide any feature for this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.